# Parse line in bash, using nova to get the line

Tags: bash, openstack

So I am running the following command to extract the information of the instance I'm interested in:

nova list | grep derpInstance

I get:

```
| 37696b22-1afa-40fa-81cc-241493ef09e1 | derpInstance    | ACTIVE | None       | Running     | devcos-shared-net-10-9-254-0_24=10.9.254.129 |
```

I'm interested in the IP address (the stuff after the = sign), how do I extract that in a shell script?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or use sed:

```
nova list | grep derpInstance | sed 's/.*=//;s/ .*//'
```

Note that solutions like these are generally brittle.  If you want a robust program you should make sure you know the grammar of the fields so that simple regular expressions don't break when characters you haven't seen before show up in the output.  For example, if an = sign can occur in any other field, this one will break.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
nova list | grep derpInstance|grep -Po '(?<==)[0-9.]*'
```